# Coexist soap 1.1 and soap 1.2

Tags: soap

I have a web service developed with soap 1.1. Among my clients who use this web service, there is someone requires the use of soap 1.2. I thought about making required changes, but in this case I'll break the work of other customers who still using soap 1.1. 
My question is: Is it possible to coexist soap 1.1 and soap 1.2 in the same application or do have to deploy two applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I found that it is possible to deploy soap 1.1 and soap 1.2 in the same application. In fact, with jax-ws implementation simply properly configure the the `sun-jaxws.xml` file and the endpoints classes.

```
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
version="2.0">
<endpoint name="Service11" implementation="mypackage.Service11Impl"
    url-pattern="/Service/11" enable-mtom="true" wsdl="/wsdl/service.wsdl" />
<endpoint name="Service12" implementation="mypackage.Service12Impl"
    url-pattern="/Service/12"
    binding="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/"
    enable-mtom="true" wsdl="/wsdl/service.wsdl" />
```

```
    @BindingType(value = javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_MTOM_BINDING)
    @WebService(...)
    public class Service11Impl extends ParentService {

    }

    @BindingType(value = javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_MTOM_BINDING)
    @WebService(...)
    public class Service112mpl extends ParentService {

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. You made my problem move one step towards solution. which library java based SOAP library is best for the use case , when the we will have  a custom code add which generates the SOAP reply.